# How do you scale images to 60% in Wordpress 3.9?

Tags: image-scaling, wordpress-3.9

In previous versions of Wordpress images could be automatically scaled to 60% with one click. Now in Wordpress 3.9 the only automatic scaling is Thumbnail, Medium, and Full Size. I could chose Custom Size or drag it to the approximate size I want, but Custom Size requires me to compute 60% myself and dragging it is inexact.

All of my images are different heights and widths. They are images of a written font so the font size needs to be the same for every image, even though the height and width are different. In the past I just made all of my images display at 60%. Is there a way to do that in Wordpress 3.9?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I couldn't find a better long term method, I just wrote some Java code to do the job. This way I can just cut and paste from the HTML view.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ImageResizer {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    String inputString;
    String outputString;

    System.out.print("Default resize is 60%\n");
    System.out.print("Type \"exit\" to quit: \n\n");

    do {
        // input something like: 
        // width="208" height="425"
        System.out.print("Enter html: ");
        inputString = userInput.nextLine();
        outputString = resize(inputString);
        System.out.print(outputString + "\n");

    } while (!inputString.equals("exit"));
}

public static String resize(String myString) {

    final int RESIZE_PERCENT = 60;

    // parse input string
    String delims = "[ ]+"; // spaces
    String[] tokens = myString.split(delims);
    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
        if (tokens[i].startsWith("width") || tokens[i].startsWith("height")) {
            // extract the height/width number
            String subDelims = "[\"]"; // quote mark
            String[] subTokens = tokens[i].split(subDelims);
            int number = Integer.parseInt(subTokens[1]);
            number = number * RESIZE_PERCENT / 100;
            // rebuild string
            tokens[i] = subTokens[0] + "\"" + number + "\"";
        }
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {

        sb.append(tokens[i]);
        if ((i + 1) < tokens.length) {
            sb.append(" ");
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
}
```